# Flask return SUM into Jinja2 list

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

im using a combination of flask and Jinja to return a template.

My SQL Statement is getting a list of "stocks" currently and looks like this:

```
stocks = db.execute("SELECT symbol,SUM(numshare),price FROM portfolio GROUP BY symbol")
return render_template("index.html",stocks=stocks)
```

and my HTML (Basic right now, just making sure I understand it first):

```
    {% for stock in stocks %}
      <p>{{stock.symbol}},{{stock.sum}},{{stock.price}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

So it's returning the symbol and price of course, but I need to return the SUM of the numshare (Which is the number of shares bought for each "Stock". So im compounding them just for easier readability.

Is there a good way to do this? Keeping in my "table" might have multiples of the same stocks at different prices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is your issue

```
SELECT symbol, 
       SUM(numshare) AS sum, 
       price 
FROM portfolio 
GROUP BY symbol
```

Note: the `AS` is not necessary, but you're writing in python. Be explicit.

Comment: Ah! good call I totally forgot about AS.  makes sense. Thanks!. This is actually Sqlite but it should work the same correct?